# SQL string connection issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, connection-string, sqlconnection

I have to establish a connection using connection string to DB.
I am using **SQL Server 2008 R2**, for which i need connection string.
It is not **SQLEXPRESS**.

Current String:

```xml
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" 
         connectionString="server=USER-PC\SQL Server;database=TLE;Connection Timeout=40" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

But it is not working. I am getting error

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

[image: Database Listing in SSMS 2008]

Comment: Are you sure your PC's name is 'USER-PC'?

Comment: Yes, because it works SQLEXPRESS..

Comment: Is `SQL Server` the name of the SQL Server instance? The instance name is configured when you install SQL Server.

Comment: @user2460637 the database I am using is compatible with SQL Server version not with Express. So, I have to use Sql Server.

Comment: @FrankPl I have added image for that. As you can see it is SQL Server 10.50.1600
If the instance is Express then it should be SQLEXPRESS instead of SQL Server.

Comment: @Ankit I am not talking about the version, but the instance **name**. If you are not aware of one you configured, maybe you are using the default instance, then leave off the `\SQL Server` after the computer name.

Comment: have you tried only using USER-PC instead of USER-PC\SQLServer

Comment: @bew Yes, I have. Then it says: Login attempt failed.

Comment: @Ankit then it found the server now you need to specify the username and the password

Comment: @Ankit That is some progress, the server is found, and replies. Which authentication modes are enabled for your SQL Server instance?

Comment: @FrankPl Windows Authentication.

Comment: @Ankit I posted an answer including the `Integrated Security=True` part.

Comment: Here is the **Answer**  **<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="server=USER-PC;database=LTS;Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=40" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/> **

Comment: @FrankPl Thanks for staying with me!!!
Can you please accept my answer, so that it can help other developers in future...

Comment: @Ankit If you posted the question, you are the only one who can accept the answer. I am not sure, if you are a new user (i. e. have low reputation), there may be some time you have to wait until you can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following connection string should probably work:

```
connectionString=
"server=USER-PC;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=TLE;Connection Timeout=40;providerName=System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Comment: Error:: {"Login failed for user ''."}

Comment: Then the currently logged in user does not have access rights to the database. This is probably not an issue of the connection string but of SQL Server security configuration.

Comment: But that user is Admin.

Comment: Is the user **SQL Server** admin or computer admin?

Comment: User is computer Admin. But there is no authentication on SQL Server.
Other users can also open it but with limited access..

Comment: @Ankit What happens if you leave out the `Initial Catalog=TLE;` part of the connection string? Can you connect? I suspect the user does not have the right to access the `TLE` database. Regarding "But there is no authentication on SQL Server.": SQL Server always uses authentication.

Comment: I am not able to connect. If I leave out Catalog.
Same Error: "Login Failed for User."

Comment: But the program where you use the connection string is running under the same user id that you used to connect to Management Studio when you created the picture in your question? And you can see the TLE database in Management Studio, and some of its tables as well?

Comment: I am using same User ID for connection String and SQL Server Management Studio. I can fully access the TLE database. I can edit its tables and data also..

Comment: If I am using the same User ID then I got ERROR:: Login Attempt Failed for User.

Comment: @Ankit That is strange. Some ideas what you could try: Are there possibly any more details about the reason of the failed logins in the Windows even log? Maybe your password expired between your login to Management Studio and your last connect attempts? If all else fails, maybe you could set up a database user (not a Windows user) in Management Studio having access and then use `User ID=name_of_the_user;Password=the_password;` instead of `Integrated Security=True;` in the connection string.

Comment: I have added another User ID to SQL studio and now the connection is established. But now I am getting another ERROR:: **{"A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)"**

Comment: Instead of login information I used **Integrated Security=True;**
It worked perfectly.

Comment: I am a bit confused now. Anyway, glad to hear you got it solved. But just for curiosity: Could you please post your final working ConnectionString?

Comment: @Ankit In SQL Server, Computer Admins are no longer given SQL Server permissions by default.  You must explicitly give that user permissions to databases in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

The connection string needs to include security information as well as the server.

Try

```
server=USER-PC;database=TLE;Connection Timeout=40;Trusted Connection=Yes
```

or

```
server=USER-PC;database=TLE;Connection Timeout=40;User ID=sqllogin;Password=something
```

Comment: Tried that but say "Login failed for user 'Ankit'."

Comment: @Ankit What login did you use to get the picture in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: create a text file and save it as "abc.udl"
Step 2: Open that abc.udl file as OLE DB Core serices.
Step 3: Choose your provider. In this case it may be "sql server Native Client..."
Step 4: In connection tab fill your server information. And Test the connection.
Step 5: If it successful the again open "abc.udl" in the nodepad
Step 6: You will get your connection string.
Step 7: Remove unnecessary things like Provider,Initial File Name,Server SPN etc.

Try this connection string :)

Answer (score 0):

Identify the sql server instance name. While installing SQL Server Express, you might have installed it under the default instance name (SQLEXPRESS). In that case you should use USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS
If you have not given the instance name and still you are unable to connect then try to give the IP address like this:

```
connectionString=
"server=Your_system_ip_address;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=TLE;Connection Timeout=40;providerName=System.Data.SqlClient"
```

For more information regarding connection strings refer to [this](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

Answer (score 0):

Below worked for me fine.. Its for SQL Server not for SQLExpress..

```xml
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ApplicationServices" 
       connectionString="server=USER-PC;database=LTS;Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=40" 
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```